# What is the simplest way to iterate over an array of arrays?

Tags: julia

Let `x::Vector{Vector{T}}`. What is the best way to iterate over all the elements of each inner vector (that is, all elements of type `T`)? The best I can come up with is a double iteration using the single-line notation, ie:

```
for n in eachindex(x), m in eachindex(x[n])
    x[n][m]
end
```

but I'm wondering if there is a single iterator, perhaps in the `Iterators` package, designed specifically for this purpose, e.g. `for i in some_iterator(x) ; x[i] ; end`.

More generally, what about iterating over the inner-most elements of any array of arrays (that is, arrays of any dimension)?

Comment: Using Iterators package: `for m in chain(x...) println(m) ; end`. Should be efficient as well.

Comment: @DanGetz Ah, that is neat! Many thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your way

```
for n in eachindex(x), m in eachindex(x[n])
    x[n][m]
end
```

is pretty fast. If you want best speed, use

```
for n in eachindex(x)
    y = x[n]
    for m in eachindex(y)
        y[m]
    end
end
```

which avoids dereferencing twice (the first dereference is hard to optimize out because arrays are mutable, and so `getindex` isn't pure). Alternatively, if you don't need `m` and `n`, you could just use

```
for y in x, for z in y
    z
end
```

which is also fast.

Note that column-major storage is irrelevant, since all arrays here are one-dimensional.

To answer your general question:

- If the number of dimensions is a compile-time constant, see [`Base.Cartesian`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/devdocs/cartesian/)
- If the number of dimensions is not a compile-time constant, use recursion

And finally, as Dan Getz mentioned in a comment:

```
using Iterators
for z in chain(x...)
    z
end
```

also works. This however has a bit of a performance penalty.

Comment: When you say `getindex` isn't pure - could you provide a bit more explanation as to what that means?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for responding - I learned a few new things from this answer. @DanGetz had a neat approach also in the comments on the question which you might want to incorporate into the answer. Cheers.

Comment: @aireties A [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) is a function that always returns the same result for the same input, and does not have any side effects. For example, `+` on numbers is pure, because `1 + 1` will always be `2`. If a compiler can detect that a function is pure, it can avoid computing it repeatedly.

Unfortunately, `getindex` is not pure, since `A[1]` might mean something different if `A` was mutated. So it is very hard for the compiler to figure out that `x[n]` does not have to be computed each time.

Comment: @ColinTBowers While neat, it doesn't give you the indices, so it isn't a replacement for the first code block. It is much slower and really not much shorter than the second code block in this answer.

Comment: @FengyangWang I agree. I really liked the simplicity of your second code block. I more meant inclduing it for the sake of completeness as it addresses the reference to `Iterators` in the question. But I'm happy either way :-)

Comment: Thank you!  This is one of the most informative SO answers on Julia I've read in a long time.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if there is a single iterator, perhaps in the Iterators package, designed specifically for this purpose, e.g. `for i in some_iterator(x) ; x[i] ; end`

Today (in Julia 1.x versions), `Iterators.flatten` is exactly this.

> help?> Iterators.flatten
>
> flatten(iter)
> Given an iterator that yields iterators, return an iterator that
> yields the elements of those iterators. Put differently, the
> elements of the argument iterator are concatenated.

```
julia> x = [1:5, [π, ℯ, 42], 'a':'e']
3-element Vector{AbstractVector}:
 1:5
 [3.141592653589793, 2.718281828459045, 42.0]
 'a':1:'e'

julia> for el in Iterators.flatten(x)
         print(el, " ")
       end
1 2 3 4 5 3.141592653589793 2.718281828459045 42.0 a b c d e 
julia>
```